# How do I patch a sys attribute using a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function which depends on the Python version. I would like to test this in a unittest by mocking `sys.version` info. The following code works:

```
def test_python_version(self):
    with patch("sys.version_info", [3]):
        my_func()
    with patch("sys.version_info", [2]):
        my_func()
```

I would like to use a decorator, but the following code does not work. Why is this? How do I set the value of the MagicMock object that gets passed into my test? Thanks

```
@patch("sys.version_info")
def test_python_version(self, mock_version_info):
        mock_version_info.return_value = [3]
        my_func()
        mock_version_info.return_value = [2]
        my_func()
```

Fails with `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'` when `my_func` tries to do `if sys.version_info[0] < 3`.

Comment: Fixed my answer, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit:

Yes it works. The original function returns a named tuple with `major`, `minor` and `micro` fields. You can mimic it by building your own named tuple. I just use a simple tuple as you access with `int` index instead. Problem with your code is in the way you indexed with `[0]` which was not right.

## Edit2:

As Zaur Nasibov pointed out `sys.version_info` is not a function, and so my code was wrong despite looking fine with the mocks (as GenError also found). I have done a little change to fix it (see GenError answer for an alternative using `PropertyMock`)

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import patch

def my_func():
    version = sys.version_info # removed the ()
    print('Detected version:', version)
    if version[0] < 3:
        print('Error: Python 3 required.')

@patch('__main__.sys')
def test_python_version(mock_sys):
        mock_sys.version_info = (3,6,2)
        my_func()
        print()
        mock_sys.version_info = (2,7,0)
        my_func()


test_python_version()
```

Outputs

```
Detected version: (3, 6, 2)

Detected version: (2, 7, 0)
Error: Python 3 required.
```

Comment: my_func() has the line: `if sys.version_info[0] < 3` which causes `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'`

Comment: @pkiller162 You missed `()`  before `[0]`. See my edit.

Comment: `sys.version_info` is not callable. `sys` module should be patched instead (see @GenError's answer).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ZaurNasibov. I have just fixed the answer. Mocks are good at making code appear to work :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer by progmatico but it has a serious issue for me, as it requires to call `sys.version_info()` instead of `sys.version_info` which would break the code if ran normally.

Example:

```
#filename: a.py
import sys
def do_something():
    if sys.version_info > (3,5):
        print('Python 3.5 or newer')
    else:
        print('Python pre 3.5')
```

Now if I want to test both cases in a unit test `@patch("sys.version_info")` will lead to an error as given by OP. Changing `do_something()` to use `sys.version_info()` would break it if the mock is not used.

Test file:

```
#filename: test_a.py
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock
import a

@patch('a.sys')
def test_a(mock_sys):
    type(mock_sys).version_info = PropertyMock(return_value=(3,4))
    a.do_something() # will show mocked python version
```

So you have to mock the sys module imported in the module a and set a `PropertyMock` on it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue with my answer. Take a look at it after the fix. You don't have to use a PropertyMock, if you don't want to.