# mock.patch decorator: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-mock

I am trying to patch a variable in module `settings` during a test method run:

```
from unittest import mock

class Test(...):

    @mock.patch('settings.TARGET_SCORES_PER_SECTION', True)
    def test_register_user(self):
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: tests.test_user.transplant_class.<locals>.C (test_register_user)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1179, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
TypeError: test_register_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I tried different approaches, could not find a solution.

What am I doing wrong?

This version works just fine:

```
    def test_register_user(self):
        with mock.patch('settings.TARGET_SCORES_PER_SECTION', True):
            self._test_register_user()

    def _test_register_user(self):
```

And I was hoping the using as a [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) would work in the same way.

Comment: Don't forget to import `settings` and add the patched mock to your test function parameters like in `def test_register_user(self, mock_target_scores):`

Comment: For what I tested both of your statements are wrong.

Comment: Wrong is a bit of a minimal description. What code have you tested? Check my answer first, hope that helps.

Comment: It is wrong in fact just because you need to patch the wholle settings not the atrribute. Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928397/how-do-i-patch-a-sys-attribute-using-a-decorator/52928562#52928562) for an alternative if you don't want to mock the whole settings module but only an attribute (uses a PropertyMock)

Comment: I noticed you don't have the `as` part in the `with` statement, which means you don't want to access the mock besides making the patch with it. Which is fine too for simple mock cases or if you setup another object to pass to patch with `new`

Comment: I am editing my answer.

Comment: While my answer works in both forms, I cannot reproduce your exact error message by changing patch and def parameters in wrong ways. Is it possible that you just forgot to put `self` in the class method for a moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, this will give you an idea of how to do it.

I have made `settings.py` hold just an assignment of `False` to `TARGET_SCORES_PER_SECTION`. Having to mention `__main__` in the patch is just a little annoyance, it won't accept a non-qualified name.

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
import settings


def register_user():
    return settings.TARGET_SCORES_PER_SECTION


class Test(TestCase):

    @patch('__main__.settings')
    def test_register_user(self, mock_settings):
        # setup your mock
        mock_settings.TARGET_SCORES_PER_SECTION = True
        # test your function
        self.assertTrue(register_user())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Edit:**

As I think to understand better OP question, the code above can also be changed to this if you like:

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
import settings


def register_user():
    return settings.TARGET_SCORES_PER_SECTION


class Test(TestCase):

    @patch('settings.TARGET_SCORES_PER_SECTION', True)
    def test_register_user(self):
        self.assertTrue(register_user())

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Where `True` is the `new` parameter. This object is used to patch the place you mention in the patch string. This might be more elegant but requires you to have a configurated object for mocking at hand.

Comment: Your solution works, but it's a workaround. My question about using `mock.patch` as a decorator according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) with `new` argument passed. Passing the mock as a function argument and setting it up in the function doesn't look nice to me. See my update of the question.

Comment: @warvariuc, but that's not done by me (not a choice). That's a decorator feature. The decorator changes your test function signature to add the mock as parameter. You can even stack decorators and they will add alll the mocks to the signature. Even if you don't use them inside, they have to be written in the def. That's why you are getting the error about `self`.

Comment: You can also decorate a class. That will change all of the test methods signatures.

Comment: Actually IT IS a choice, sorry. From the docs, "If patch() is used as a decorator and new is omitted, the created mock is passed in as an extra argument to the decorated function. If patch() is used as a context manager the created mock is returned by the context manager."

Comment: I found the issue. It's nose2 test runner. When I want to test a single TestCase method (`./manage.sh runtests -r -v tests.test_user.Test.test_register_user`), it passes a function not bound to `self`. Haven't figured out yet why it does so and how to fix this, but it's already a different issue. `mock.patch` works correctly. Thank you for your time.